# Getting mathematical difference between fields from two tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am using Asp.Net Entity Framework. I have 2 tables and I want to make a minus between two variables which are in different tables. I made join but it's not working. Here is my code:

```
var prod_items = (from prod in entity.ProductSet 
                  join ca in entity.CartSet 
                  on prod.ProductID equals ca.Product_ProductID 
                  where ca.Customer_CustomerID.Equals(id) 
                  select new { ca.Quantity,prod.ProductStock,prod.ProductID });
int h;

foreach (var nbr in prod_items) 
{
    h = nbr.ProductStock - nbr.Quantity;
    ProductSet p = entity.ProductSet
                         .Where(i => i.ProductID == nbr.ProductID)
                         .FirstOrDefault();
    p.ProductStock = h;
}
```

I get an error like `ArgumentException` was unhandled by user code.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
var prod_items = (from prod in entity.ProductSet 
                  join ca in entity.CartSet 
                  on prod.ProductID equals ca.Product_ProductID 
                  where ca.Customer_CustomerID.Equals(id) 
                  select new ProductSet 
                  {
                      ProductID = prod.ProductID,
                      ProductStock =  prod.ProductStock - ca.Quantity,
                      // Set the values for th rest properties.
                  });
```